# header() not redirecting to another index page automatically

Tags: php

when i click login.. it doesn't automatically redirect me to home.php, i have to refresh the page for it to redirect me. I'm guess the first header() is working fine bc it is responding to a page refresh. what's not working is the second header() inside the if statement. What am i doing wrong? Thank you so much for your help.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']!=""){
  header("Location: home.php");
}

include_once 'db.php';

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uname']);
 $upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['upass']);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$uname'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

 if($row['password']==$upass){
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
  header("Location: home.php");
}
else{
  echo "Unable to log in, please try again.";
}

}

?>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="User Name" required /><br>
      <input type="text" name="upass" placeholder="Password" required /><br>
      <button type="submit" name="login">login</button>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['logout']))
{
 session_destroy();
 unset($_SESSION['user']);

 header("Location: index.php"); 
}
?>
    Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
        <form method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="logout">Sign Out</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

db.php

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli();
$conn->connect('localhost', 'singta', 'Lante1', 'wuzzdb');

if ($conn->connect_errno) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error; } 
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']!=""){
  header("Location: home.php");
}else{
    echo "You're not logged In";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>
    <a href="login.php">Login Here</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `header()` function call sends a header to the browser telling it where to go, but it does not stop the execution of the PHP script. So after a `header()` call used for redirection you should in almost all cases put an `exit;` directly after it.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']!=""){
  header("Location: home.php");
  exit;
}
```

Also on your second `header()` call.

**Additional note**

You should also be checking that `$_SESSION['user']` exists before attempting to test it like this

```
session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']!=""){
  header("Location: home.php");
  exit;
}
```

This needs doing whereever you test for the `user` in the session as if they are not logged in it wont actually exist.

This is one of the problems with learning PHP on a LIVE server where the display of errors is turned off. So while you are learning or even after, while developing a script on a live server remember to add these 2 lines to the top of the scripts you are developing

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

But then remember to remove then when a a script is working as its bad form to show a user this kind of error.

Comment: Thanks @maxhb much more precise now.

Comment: after putting exit; after both header() when i click login, the page goes blank and the url still stays at /login.php.. only page refresh will redirect

Comment: Hmmm there must be something else wrong, give me a minute

Comment: Are you sure that this script and `home.php` exist in the same folder?

Comment: when i echo something right after the second header() for testing.. the code seem to run all the way through and echos but skipping the redirect

Comment: I assume this script is `index.php` does `home.php` actually have any HTML is it, as if you are not logged in this code will throw you into `home.php` Check what it says in the browsers address bar when you see a blank page

Comment: yes home.php does have html in it. i have both index.php and home.php. home.php is when logged in and index.php is when logged out. when logged in.. index.php will redirect to home.php

Comment: Well I just loaded your `index.php` code with the 2 `exit;` added and tested it here and it works just fine.

Comment: the script that goes blank is login.php and the url is mydomain.com/login.php i'm assuming when i put exit; after the second header() the rest of the code doesn't get run.. therefore the form is blank?

Comment: Can you add `home.php` to your question, as like I say it works for me, but my `home.php` just does a `print_r($_SESSION);` to proove that the user has been added to the session array

Comment: yes. my home.php is working fine. it just has a logout button and welcome 'user'. the logout is redirecting me to index.php as expected. i updated the code with home.php

Comment: is yours automatically redirecting it to home.php when click on login? the user is being added fine.. its just that its not automatically redirecting to home.php without refreshing the page

Comment: Yes it is. Works if I user a real user/pass and also if I use a non existant user/pass and also if I use a real userid and the wrong password

Comment: Maybe you should add your `db.php` possibly there is an error in there

Comment: I just made my `db.php` fail to login and removed the error checking after the `mysqli_connect()` and I get the blank page issue. I can therefore assume your error is in your `db.php`

Comment: I would bet money its your `db.php` code. Add that to your question as well

Comment: i added db.php to question... it seem to be connecting fine when fetching data from database

Comment: Yes that also works, so would have lost my money! So now I am completely out of ideas.

Comment: Last try: Are you sure that your session setting in php.ini are not causing issues? Have you looked at your php error log for clues? Make sure you have `display_errors = On` or maybe add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to all your scripts to see if that identifies the issue

Comment: can you test to see if it works on your end at the actual website www.wuzzgood.com.. you can test with username ggg and pwd ggg. thanks

i haven't looked into php.ini yet.. i'll look into it

Comment: using `ggg/ggg` I get the login page thrown back at me with the 2 fields blank. I see you are testing on a live site, so add the `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to all these pages as live sites normally run with error display turned off, maybe that will show something

Comment: yes.. and then if you refresh the page it'll redirect you to home.php. in home.php if you click logout.. it logs you out and redirect you to index.php automatically without having to refresh. so logout is working fine but login is not. even though it threw you back to 2 empty fields but technically at that point you're already logged in.. its just not redirecting you automatically

Comment: Ahh yes I see, Hmmmm

Comment: Hang on. Your `index.php` is not what I assumed. I assumed it was the code you first posted. So what is the code for your `index.php`

Comment: i added index.php to question. the first code was login.php. i also have register.php which is also not redirecting automatically. the user info seem to be getting inserted fine when sign up

Comment: You have not added `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to your code! Can you do that please. Riht after the `<?php` on all scripts

Comment: im getting these errors after i added those error reporting codes. when i go to index.php i get 
Notice: Undefined index: user in /home/lys916/public_html/index.php on line 8.......
when i go to login.php i get
Notice: Undefined index: user in /home/lys916/public_html/login.php on line 7.......
and home.php i get
Notice: Undefined index: user in /home/lys916/public_html/home.php on line 13

Comment: Ok, now I see the problem, give me a minute or 2

Comment: im also getting this warning in login.php when click login button.

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/lys916/public_html/login.php:7) in /home/lys916/public_html/login.php on line 25

Comment: yea, thats because php is now echoing error messages because you are not checking if `isset($_SESSION['user'])` before attempting to use it. Fix that problem and the `modify headers` message will go away

Comment: wow.. i knew it was isset from the beginning.. i had already added it before and testedit but for whatever reason the issue didn't go away. i thought it was something else. now i tried it again adding the isset.. and its all working. thank you so much. i made it harder than it should be.